# How to make child elements from parent1 have a higher z-index than child elements from parent 2 (with same z-index as other parent)?

Tags: css, html, position, z-index

I have the following HTML:

**HTML**

```
<div id="map">
  <div class="parent">
    <svg>
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <svg>
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 700px;
}

svg {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

***Abbreviations:***

first parent-element: **p1**

second parent-element: **p2**

child-elements from p1: **c1**

child-elements from p2: **c2**

***Background info:***

Both parent-elements are positioned exactly above each other. It seems that the p2 is "a complete layer above the p1".

***Problem/Question:***

Currently i can NOT click on ANY c1. No chance. The p2 seems to be a complete layer above the p1. How do I manage that c2 still are above c1 BUT I am able to click on c1 if there are no c2 directly above them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add `pointer-events: none` to the `.parent` divs and then add `pointer-events:all` to the `.child` divs.

This would mean only the actual children can be clicked. If there is no c2 then c1 should be clickable

something like this?
http://jsfiddle.net/ekL6632c/1/

Comment: Brilliant solution! How did you find out about the property 'pointer-events' in the first place?

Comment: Glad it worked! Can't really remember, just 'picked it up' from other code (probably another SO question/answer!) You can find more info here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events